# How to remove a string from a single variable

Tags: python

A function which can return multiple string:

```
from facebook_scraper import get_posts
    for post in get_posts('LearningEnglishAmericanWay', pages=1):
    s=(post['post_url'])
    print(s)
```

I got this result:

```
URL1
URL2
```

How can I remove the first string?

Comment: Are you trying to only get the first string or remove duplicates?

Comment: To start, what is posted in the question is neither a function, nor does (the non-function) return anything.  Please clarify the question.

Comment: @Crapy get the second string only

Comment: @jonesliu I have added a solution then in the answers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I will use list comprehension and indexing:

```
print(type([post['post_url'] for post in get_posts('LearningEnglishAmericanWay', pages=1)][-1]))
```

Comment: This doesn't eliminate the first string.

Comment: Okay.  I didn't see the whole program (with the [-1] index).  Technically what this program is doing is keeping the last string, not removing the first string.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility:

```
from facebook_scraper import get_posts
for post in list(get_posts('LearningEnglishAmericanWay', pages=1))[1:]:
    s=(post['post_url'])
    print(s)
```

Another:

```
from facebook_scraper import get_posts
first = True
for post in get_posts('LearningEnglishAmericanWay', pages=1):
    s=(post['post_url'])
    if not first:
        print(s)
    else:
        first = False
```